# How to write Python code that does cumprod for forward 2 periods with groupby

Tags: python-3.x

I want to calculate Return, RET, which is Cumulative of 2 periods (now & next period) with `groupby(id)`.

```
df['RET'] = df.groupby('id')['trt1m1'].rolling(2,min_periods=2).apply(lambda x:x.prod()).reset_index(0,drop=True)
```

#### Expected Result:

```
id  datadate    trt1m1  RET
1   20051231    1   2
1   20060131    2   6
1   20060228    3   12
1   20060331    4   16
1   20060430    4   20
1   20060531    5   Nan
2   20061031    10  110
2   20061130    11  165
2   20061231    15  300
2   20070131    20  420
2   20070228    21  Nan
```

#### Actual Result:

```
id  datadate    trt1m1  RET
1   20051231    1   Nan
1   20060131    2   2
1   20060228    3   6
1   20060331    4   12
1   20060430    4   16
1   20060531    5   20
2   20061031    10  Nan
2   20061130    11  110
2   20061231    15  165
2   20070131    20  300
2   20070228    21  420
```

The code i used calculate cumprod for trailing 2 periods instead of forward.

Comment: you need `df.RET.shift(-1)`